# No job configuration with the name [jobName] was registered error in Spring boot Application. Spring version 3.1.0, spring batch version 5.0.2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to restart a job which was exited with the status code "FAILED" through a rest end point.

The job is scheduled at a particular time and it has failed for some reason.

If I try to restart the job via above rest API getting the error "No job configuration with the name [updateJob] was registered"

The execution Id passed to rest end point is extracted from the db(job repository)

I can see the job with the the name "updateJob" in the table "BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION". Still I am getting the error "No job configuration with the name [updateJob] was registered".

```
@Log4j2
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/jobs")
public class JobController {

    private final JobOperator jobOperator;
    private final JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    public JobController(JobOperator jobOperator, JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
        this.jobOperator = jobOperator;
        this.jobExplorer = jobExplorer;
    }

    @GetMapping("/restart")
    public ResponseEntity<String> restartJob(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {

        try {
            final Long restartId = jobOperator.restart(id);
            final JobExecution restartExecution = jobExplorer.getJobExecution(restartId);
            assert restartExecution != null;
            final ExitStatus status = restartExecution.getExitStatus();
            log.info("Job exited with status: {}", status.getExitDescription());
            return ResponseEntity.ok("started");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unable to restart job: {}", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.ok("ended with an error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig {

 @Bean
    Job updateLinkStatusJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step step) {
        return new JobBuilder("updateJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }

@Bean
    public Step step(JobRepository jobRepository,
                                     PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                     MyItemReader reader,
                                     MyItemWriter writer) {
        return new StepBuilder("updateStep", jobRepository)
                .<StatusUpdateDTO, StatusUpdateDTO>chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager)
                .reader(reader)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Please suggest me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means the job you are trying to restart is not registered in the `JobRegistry` used by the `JobOperator`. You need to add a bean of type `JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor` in the application context, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#jobregistrybeanpostprocessor